# How to select a given feature in a geojson file using python?

Tags: python, gis, geojson

**Scenario:**

I have a large (120+ MB) .geojson file that represents a bunch of `LineStrings` features.

Here is an example `feature` selected using `json.dumps(geoFile['features'][0])`:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 0,
    "properties": {
        "FID": 0,
        "prop1": 1,
        "prop2": "thing2",
        "prop3": "thing3"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -99.491525,
                35.306851,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491485,
                35.306705,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491451,
                35.306581,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491417,
                35.306456,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491375,
                35.306321,
                0
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Goal:**

- Select a `feature` based on the property value in `prop1`.
- Render the selected `feature` on a `geopandas` map (or other python map) along with some georeferenced points from dataframes being used elsewhere in the app.

**Questions:**

- What is the python syntax for selecting the `feature` from the geojson file based on `properties/prop`?

  - Obviously I know how to select based on index (`[0]`), but I can't find examples of selecting by `prop1`.
  - **Tried:** `json.dumps(geoFile['features'][0]['properties']['prop1'] == 1)` but this just returns `true`
- Is `geopandas` a suitable a mapping library to use for this type of mashup?

  - In the end, I'd like to use `Dash` or the like to make the `feature` selection and the rendered points interactive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming here geoFile is just a python dict, and you are converting that to stringified json with `json.dumps`, then you can use dictionary comprehension as

```py
features = [f for f in geoFile["features"] if f["properties"]["prop1"]==1]
```

This should give you a list of feature dicts that satisfy the condition.
Now you can wrap this in whatever way you wish. A simple thing to do would be to put this list under a key, just like the initial features list was under `"features"` key.
`json.dumps({"features": features})`